# How to use __webpack_public_path__ variable in a Webpack configuration?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, typescript2.0

I am currently working on a web application using React, TypeScript and Webpack. I want Webpack to generate images URLs according to a subdomain that I only know on runtime and not during the compile time.

I've read this on Webpacks's documentation:
http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-publicpath

> Note: In cases when the eventual publicPath of of output files isn’t known at compile time, it can be left blank and set dynamically at runtime in the entry point file. If you don’t know the publicPath while compiling you can omit it and set **webpack_public_path** on your entry point.
>
> > **webpack_public_path** = myRuntimePublicPath
> >
> > // rest of your application entry

But I can't get it working.

I've set the `webpack_public_path` variable in my app entry point. But how can I use its value in my Webpack config?
I need to use it here:

> "module": {
>               "rules": [
>                   {
>                       "test": /.(png|jpg|gif)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/,
>                       "loaders": [`url?limit=8192&name=/images/[hash].[ext]`]
>                   }
>              ]
>   }

I need to do something like this:

> "loaders": ['url?limit=8192&name=**__webpack_public_path__**/images/[hash].[ext]']

## ANSWER

I've managed to make it work. So in my entry point file (start.tsx), I declare de `__webpack_public_path__` free var before the imports and I assign its value after the imports.

```
/// <reference path="./definitions/definitions.d.ts" />
declare let __webpack_public_path__;

import './styles/main.scss';

/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */
import * as React from 'react';
/* tslint:enable:no-unused-variable */
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as Redux from 'redux';
import { Root } from './components/root';

__webpack_public_path__ = `/xxxx/dist/`;
```

Now, the public path is being used when I have an `img` tag:

```html
<img src={require('../../images/logo.png')} />
```

Turns into:

```html
<img src='/xxxx/dist/images/125665qsd64134fqsf.png')} />
```

Answer (score 15):

Here's my basic setup in terms of the generated HTML:

```html
<script>
    window.resourceBaseUrl = 'server-generated-path';
</script>
<script src="path-to-bundle" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

My main entry point script:

```js
__webpack_public_path__ = window.resourceBaseUrl;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had something similar but had issues due to the use of Typescript. I will edit my question with upaded code.

Comment: doesnt seems to work for me for some reason. using react with es6

Comment: If you have an issue with ES6, do what the note says in https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/#on-the-fly. This worked for me.

Comment: I suppose your bundle is also on the server as a resource, under the baseUrl path, so how do you make the `path-to-bundle` dynamic with `server-generated-path` ?

Comment: im trying to understand what the context for `__webpack_public_path__`. is this a global that is expected to already be defined by webpack?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the order I was loading my scripts in my `index.html`. Ensure the last `<script>` tag in your `index.html` has a `src` attribute.

I discovered this by reading through the generated webpack code:

```js
var scriptUrl;
if (__webpack_require__.g.importScripts) scriptUrl = __webpack_require__.g.location + "";
var document = __webpack_require__.g.document;
if (!scriptUrl && document) {
    if (document.currentScript)
        scriptUrl = document.currentScript.src
    if (!scriptUrl) {
        var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
        if(scripts.length) scriptUrl = scripts[scripts.length - 1].src
    }
}
// When supporting browsers where an automatic publicPath is not supported you must specify an output.publicPath manually via configuration
// or pass an empty string ("") and set the __webpack_public_path__ variable from your code to use your own logic.
if (!scriptUrl) throw new Error("Automatic publicPath is not supported in this browser");
scriptUrl = scriptUrl.replace(/#.*$/, "").replace(/\?.*$/, "").replace(/\/[^\/]+$/, "/");
__webpack_require__.p = scriptUrl;
```

It just looks through your scripts and picks the last one to set as the `scriptUrl` which it then uses to figure out if you are using a "`publicPath"` or not. Since my last script did not have a `src` attribute, all changes to `__webpack_public_path__` or webpack.config.js `{ ..., output: { publicPath: "" }}` were being ignored.

My original `index.html`:

```html
      <body>
        <div id="root">
          ${html}
        </div>
        
        <script src="/static/runtime.js" type="module"></script>
        <script src="/static/polyfills.js" type="module"></script>
        <script src="/static/vendor.js" type="module"></script>
        <!-- the below is the offending script -->
        <script>
          // WARNING: See the following for security issues around embedding JSON in HTML:
          // https://redux.js.org/usage/server-rendering#security-considerations
          window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(preloadedState).replace(
            /</g,
            '\\u003c'
          )}
        </script>
      </body>
```

My `index.html` after my changes:

```html
      <body>
        <div id="root">
          ${html}
        </div>
        <script>
          // WARNING: See the following for security issues around embedding JSON in HTML:
          // https://redux.js.org/usage/server-rendering#security-considerations
          window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(preloadedState).replace(
            /</g,
            '\\u003c'
          )}
        </script>
        <script src="/static/runtime.js" type="module"></script>
        <script src="/static/polyfills.js" type="module"></script>
        <script src="/static/vendor.js" type="module"></script>
      </body>
```

This took me several days to fix.

Answer (score -1):

Not a big webpack expert, but I'm not sure you are using that loader in the right way. The url-loader is there to help you load files data that are required/imported in your code.

So if in your entry point you write something like:

```
var imageData = require("path/to/my/file/file.png");
```

Webpack will see that you are trying to import something different than a .js file and then will search in your configured loader list, to see if it can use any loader to load that resource.

Since you had set up a loader whith a `test` property that matches your required resource type (extension .png), it will use that configured loader (url-loader) to try loading that resource into your bundle.

You can also tell webpack what loader he needs to use by prepending the loader (and some query strings if you wish) in the require path:

```
var imageData = require("url-loader?mimetype=image/png!path/to/my/file/file.png");
```

Also, I'm not sure there is even a `name` parameter you can pass to the [url-loader](https://github.com/webpack/url-loader/blob/master/index.js).

Comment: Thanks for your anwer. the `name` parameter exists, we are using it beacause we had issues with the files being generated in the wrong folder. I've managed to get it working, i am going to update my post with the answer.

Comment: Glad you made it, I'm curious to see your updated post.

Comment: Is there a difference between loading assets with `import` and with `require`?